# Is it possible to send DTMF tones to an IVR from computer keyboard?

Tags: twilio, ivr, dtmf

I am developing a soft phone having ability to make outbound calls from a browser using Twilio. For some outbound calls we have to connect to an IVR and input digits or pounds. Is there a way we can send these inputs from computer keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Twilio supports sending DTMF from the Programmable Voice SDK Client. You can find more details below.

[Twilio Client JS SDK: Twilio.Device](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device)

[.sendDigits( digits )](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#sendDigits)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Its exactly what I was looking for.